# Множественное наследование в php

Tags: php, наследование, множественное-наследование

Возможно ли наследование свойств и методов от нескольких классов в php?
Если да, то приведите пример, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 9):

> *Возможно ли наследование свойств и методов от нескольких классов в php?*

В чистом виде - нет, но начиная с версии 5.4.0, PHP реализует метод для повторного использования кода под названием трейт (trait).

[Цитата:](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php)

---

Трейт - это механизм обеспечения повторного использования кода в языках с поддержкой только одиночного наследования, таких как PHP. Трейт предназначен для уменьшения некоторых ограничений одиночного наследования, позволяя разработчику повторно использовать наборы методов свободно, в нескольких независимых классах и реализованных с использованием разных архитектур построения классов. Семантика комбинации трейтов и классов определена таким образом, чтобы снизить уровень сложности, а также избежать типичных проблем, связанных с множественным наследованием и смешиванием (mixins).

Трейт очень похож на класс, но предназначен для группирования функционала хорошо структурированым и последовательным образом. Невозможно создать самостоятельный экземпляр трейта. Это дополнение к обычному наследованию и позволяет сделать горизонтальную композицию поведения, то есть применение членов класса без необходимости наследования.

Пример:

```
<?php
trait ezcReflectionReturnInfo {
    function getReturnType() { /*1*/ }
    function getReturnDescription() { /*2*/ }
}

class ezcReflectionMethod extends ReflectionMethod {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;
    /* ... */
}

class ezcReflectionFunction extends ReflectionFunction {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;
    /* ... */
}
```

* *Подробнее можно почитать в официальной документации по ссылке выше.*

Answer (score 0):

Если вам это понадобилось в PHP, значит пора внедрять [интерфейсы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.interfaces.php). Свойства вы так не унаследуете, но опять таки если вам это понадобилось, пора от них избавляться в пользу методов.